# Touch events not working Google Maps API Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, touch-event

The following code should allow a double-tap on a mobile device to simulate a right-click on PC to drop a pin on a Google Map, but doesn't. I've racked my brain trying to figure out why it doesn't work.  Any one see anything wrong with this code?  Testing on IOS. I swear this code used to work!  The problem is touch events do nothing, the map flashes and doesn't trigger the drop a pin code like it does on a desktop.

````
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function (event) {
            addMarkerToMap(event.latLng);
        });

        domMap.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            //map.setZoom(8);
            //map.setCenter(overlay.getPosition()); // set map center to marker position
            mobileAndTabletcheck() && setTimeout(mySingleClickBelovedFunction(e), 200);
        });

        var singleClickInProgess = false;
        function doDoubleClickProcessing(event)
        {
            console.log('dblclick'); 
            isDblClick = true;
            myDlbClickBelovedFunction(event);
        }
        function handleClickONMarker(e)
        {
            if ( singleClickInProgess )
            {
                singleClickInProgess = false;
                doDoubleClickProcessing(e);
            } 
            else
            {
                singleClickInProgess = true;
                setTimeout(checkClickONMarkerStatus,300);
            }       
        }

        function checkClickONMarkerStatus()
        {
            if ( singleClickInProgess  )
            {
                singleClickInProgess = false;
                console.log('single click');
             }
            singleClickInProgess = false;
        }



        function mySingleClickBelovedFunction(e) {
            if (!isDblClick) {
                // DO MY SINGLE CLICK BUSINESS :)  
                //smoothZoom(map, 12, map.getZoom());
            }
            handleClickONMarker(e);
            // DO NOTHING
        }

        domMap.addEventListener('dblclick', function (event) {
            //alert('test');
            if (mobileAndTabletcheck()) {
                isDblClick = true;
                myDlbClickBelovedFunction(event);
            }
        });

        function myDlbClickBelovedFunction(event) {
            //debugger
            console.log(event);

            overlay.setMap(map);

            //Work out the coordinates on the map
            var x = (event.offsetX),
                y = (event.offsetY);

            var point = new google.maps.Point(x, y),
                latLng = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);

            addMarkerToMap(latLng);

            overlay.setMap(null);
        }

        // the smooth zoom function
        function smoothZoom(map, max, cnt) {
            if (cnt >= max) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                y = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function (event) {
                    google.maps.event.removeListener(y);
                    smoothZoom(map, max, cnt + 1);
                });
                setTimeout(function () { map.setZoom(cnt) }, 80);
            }
        }```

Thanks!
````

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue has been reported in our **Google Public Issue Tracker**, however it has already been marked fixed. Would you mind reviewing the entry? Here's the issue:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/35822092
- https://issuetracker.google.com/35824421

If they are not similar, please file a new issue. Make sure to provide us with a self contained sample (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem and include specific steps to reproduce.

Google Public Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.